# Detect if a bitmap's dimensions can be reduced without losing information

Tags: image, image-processing, image-resizing, image-compression

I'm looking for a library or algorithm that will make a bitmap as small as it can be without losing information. For instance, given a 600x400 solid black image, I want to get a 3x2 solid black image.

My use case: I have a database of flag images that I want to optimize. Many flags, like France and Italy, are made out of blocks of solid color, so the pngs can be much smaller than the high resolution I use for detailed flags like Spain. I generate the png database by exporting an often-updated database of flag SVGs ripped from Wikimedia. I want to integrate the described lossless resizing into the export pipeline.

I've tried to find this information online, but I'm not really sure how to describe my problem with a few keywords. I keep finding stuff about lossless compression, which is different from lossless resizing.

Comment: "which is different from lossless resizing." - that's because it's mathematically impossible to downscale raster graphics without losing information. Even if an image was upscaled and then downscaled, there's still information-loss (granted, in the case of most national flags that would be a *low* information-loss, but if you scale say, Saudi Arabia's flag, then you'll lose lots of information).

Comment: Why not keep the flag images as SVGs and render them on-demand?

Comment: "it's mathematically impossible to downscale raster graphics without losing information." What about the example in my post -- 600x400 solid black to 3x2 solid black?

Comment: "Why not keep the flag images as SVGs and render them on-demand?" Unfortunately this is far too slow. All flag images need to be loaded into VRAM (this is for a real-time rendered video game). The conversion process from SVG to a format readable by the GPU takes several minutes for the hundreds of flags, but just a few seconds with PNGs. I'm hoping to drop it to under a second by using DDS compression.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52243679/lossless-texture-compression-for-opengl
It seems that lossless texture compression is not feasible. An idea is that use DDS, encode and decode, check if there is loss in data. If the data is lost, use PNG compression.

Comment: You misunderstand, I am not trying to compress the texture losslessly, I am trying to resize it losslessly. For example a 100x100 solid black image can be turned into a 1x1 solid black image.

Perhaps I phrased the question badly, but I'm not sure how else to say it.

Comment: @Iamsodarncool In that particular case no information is lost, correct - however the consumer of that black `3x2px` image has no idea what the original image looked like - and that is an example of information loss (i.e. it doesn't know the original was a black 600x400px image). As for your example of the French flag: that only works for flags with even proportions, which is a tiny minority of all flags used today. How would you represent the US flag or any of these? https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/86573/10-unexpected-emblems-flags-world

Comment: I understand that you want to resize flags losslessly. At this point, @Dai is right, downscaling and upscaling causes information loss. I suggest looking at [aspect ratios of flags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_aspect_ratios_of_national_flags) and writing a function for each flag for rendering, by using templates where necessary. You cannot have the flag of Czech Republic shrunk, but you can easily render it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up calculating this manually for flags where it's relevant, and including that information in my flag database. Most flag SVGs get exported at the requested maximum resolution, but if they have a supplied `minimum resolution without data loss` that is lower, they get exported at that. So for instance, my database now contains `minimum resolution without data loss` of 3x2 for France and 5x3 for Germany.

Answer (score 0):

Lossless resizing seems impossible. Because you will be mapping blocks of pixels (say 2x2 or 5x3...) to a single pixel throughout the image and for this to be reversible, all the pixels in a block must be of exactly the same color.

But the probability that an image be made exclusively of such uniform blocks is zero, even for small reduction factors.

Comment: It isn't zero - but it means that the OP's pet-idea only works for flags with only colour blocks that are sized in integral fractions (e.g. the French flag's aspect-ratio is 3:2 with 3 vertical colour bars - so that's an ideal example that works, but the UK flag has triangular-shaped regions that cannot be represented as rectangular pixel blocks - let alone the Nepalese flag)

Comment: @Dai: works provided the three bars are exactly the same width. A single pixel difference will spoil everything. For a test, I randomly took a French flag from the Web. Image width: 1000 ! I told you: probability 0, don't even think of it.

Answer (score 0):

Just save full-resolution PNG images, then run the PNGs through optimizers like [optipng](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/) and [AdvanceComp's](https://github.com/amadvance/advancecomp) advdef. PNG should, out of the box, do an amazingly good job compressing images with large regions of solid color.

> For instance, given a 600x400 solid black image, I want to get a 3x2 solid black image.
> [...]
> Many flags, like France and Italy, are made out of blocks of solid color, so the pngs can be much smaller than the high resolution I use for detailed flags like Spain.

I did an experiment to test this idea, and the difference is underwhelming. I generated two PNGs of solid black, one of size 600x400 and another of size 3x2, then optimized with `optipng -strip all`. The results:

```
black-600x400.png:  124 bytes
black-3x2.png:       68 bytes
```

A difference of just a few dozen bytes. Also, it's worth noting that at this extreme, much of the PNG file size is the mandatory bytes that make up the file header, chunk structure, etc., not the image data itself.

Comment: You are correct that on disk the difference is small. However, when uploaded to VRAM, the difference becomes significant. PNG is not the main format that I need the images to be optimized for, it's just the format I'm storing them in currently.